# Connect to Firebird 3.0 embedded database in delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac, firebird-3.0

I created an application using Delphi Professional 10.1 to connect to a Firebird 3.0 database using FireDAC.  I can connect without a problem if I have the FB server running.  Recently, I needed to temporarily deploy the application and database to another computer which does not have the FB server installed. Since I didn't want to install FB on the new computer, I decided to run it as an embedded server.

So, I created a folder on the new computer and copied the application exe file, the database, FDDrivers.ini, FDConnectionDefs.ini, firebird.conf, fbclient32.dll and engine12.dll into it.  When I start the application, I get the following error message:

[image]

Here is the contents of FDDrivers.ini

```
[FDDrivers.ini]
Encoding=UTF8

[FB30]
; FB30 virtual driver will use specified Firebird client library
BaseDriverID=FB
VendorLibWin32=fbclient.dll
Embedded=TRUE
```

Here is the contents of FDConnectionDefs.ini

```
[FDConnectionDefs.ini]
Encoding=UTF8


[SmartData - Server]
Database=Smartdata.fdb
DriverID=FB30
ExtendedMetadata=True
Dialect=3
Protocol=Local
```

How do I fix this?  I thought with an embedded database that usernames and passwords were ignored.  Even when I used a username and password, I got the same error.

Comment: Having only `fbclient.dll` and `engine12.dll` is not enough, which will result in fbclient connecting to the localhost Firebird server instead, iirc. You need a lot more of the Firebird files for it to work, see https://lawinegevaar.nl/firebird/jaybird_embedded_example.html#_details_on_embedded_use for a list of files.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I can now connect to the database, but I am getting another error message:  "no permission for SELECT access to table T_SCHOOL".  What do I do next?

Comment: I figured out what to do.  I had to grant permissions all to Public for all objects.  Once I did that, it worked!  Does this create security issues for the database if it is on a server?

Comment: Granting to public would allow anyone with a password on the server to access the database and all tables, that isn't great from a security perspective. The alternative is to grant the necessary rights to a user, and use that user on connect (an empty password should do).

Comment: Thanks for your help.